# Show that $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, asymptotics

If
$f$ is a well defined piecewise differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and as $x\to \infty$ $$f(x)=x\log x-x+O(\log x)$$ then prove that $f(x)$ is a monotone increasing function (at least for $x$ sufficiently large) .

I could not think of a counter example for $f$.

In a research article, I read that if $g$ is well defined piecewise differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and as $x\to \infty$ $$g'(x)=-\log x+O(x^{-2})$$ then $g(x)$ is a monotone decreasing function.

Any help will surely be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Please add context of problem and show your attempt , please add the link of research article.

Comment: The big-oh notation here only tells you about the absolute size, not about the rate of change.  The $x\log(x) -x$ will be pretty smooth, so if you make the $O(\log x)$ part very wiggly then its derivative will dominate $f'(x)$.

Comment: For example $1/x \sin e^x$ tends to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ but its derivative becomes exponentially large. It just tends to $0$ in a very, very  wiggly way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. If $f(x)= x\log x -x + 2\sin (x) \log x$, then $f$ is never monotone for $x$ large enough.

The difference with the second statement (on $g$) is that the condition on $g^\prime$ implies that $g^\prime(x) \geq 0$ for $x$ large enough. That's a statement on the sign of the derivative, which implies monotonicity of $g$. However, you cannot start with a statement on the size of $f$ and hope that it implies anything on the sign of $f^\prime$.

Comment: That was my initial counterexample too, but if you actually take the derivative you get $\log(x) +\cos(x)$, which is eventually strictly positive. Maybe something with $\sin(x^2)$?

Comment: You're right. I've modified the example a bit. Take another look?